Выбор ML модели для рекомендательной системы
Нужно создать рекомендательную систему для рекомендации пользователям различных ивентов
Задача - по запросу рекомендовать конкретному пользователю n наиболее релевантных событий на основе истории его взаимодействия с другими мероприятиями
История взаимодействия представлена отметками о просмотре карточки мероприятия конкретным пользователем, лайком/дизлайком, временем просмотра  и фактом открытия подробного описания (матрица достаточно разреженная)
Постоянно обновляемый список мероприятий представлен набором сущностей с описанием,картинками,датами проведения,классами(непересекающимися) и тэгами(пересекающимися)
На данный момент есть несколько предположений как можно реализовать такую функциональность (двухбашенная модель с анализом истории взаимодействия при помощи трасформера и эмбеддингами для мероприятий/факторизационная машина/коллаборативная фильтрация)
Список мероприятий постоянно обновляется, поэтому первоначальная идея с коллаборативный фильтрацией скорее всего не подойдет
Помогите определить, какую модель будет в данном случае будет актуальнее использовать для решения вышеупомянутой задачи, что почитать чтобы разобраться в вопросе самостоятельно
Более предпочитаемым будет масштабируемое решение, которое можно будет дополнять по мере необходимости (например расширить эмбеддинг ивентов добавив к описанию картинки или добавить учет новых видов явного/неявного фидбэка )
